# Override tab navigation for XAML ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want a list of items that are selectable, so naturally I chose ListBox. However the tab/arrowing behavior is not what I want. I need the tab behavior of ItemsControl without the arrow key functionality. So if I have three UIElements like:

- ButtonA
- ListBox
- ButtonB

then the tab order will be:

ButtonA, ListBoxItem1, ... ListBoxItemN, ButtonB, ButtonA, ....

Unfortunately the default ListBox tab navigation makes the tab order:

ButtonA, ListBoxSelectedItem, ButtonB, ButtonA, ....

All is well if I use an ItemsControl, but ItemsControl has no selected item logic.

Comment: Set your ListBoxItem's Focusable property to false via ItemContainerStyle.

Answer (score 1):

setting the `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation` in the `ListBox` to `"Continue"` should do it :

```
 <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="ButtonA"/>
        <ListBox KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue">
            <ListBoxItem Content="One"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Two"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Three"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Four"/>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="ButtonB"/>
    </StackPanel>
```